# To get security clearance, do I need to be national of the country?

Tags: legal

For example, if I want to apply to a job based in UK which requires security clearance, can I only do so if I'm a British national? What if I'm from another country belonging to the EU?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Personnel Security.

Comment: @lynks To most of **IT security** positions, you are required to pass a security clearance test. I don't see the off-topic.

Comment: Most **IT Security** jobs involve sitting on a **chair**, and using a **keyboard**, we don't answer questions about peripherals here though.

Comment: Personally, I think this is on topic here. We agreed some time back that the scope needs to include not only IT security but also policy, standards, physical security and if I remember correctly, personnel vetting.

Comment: It really depends on several factors.  There isn't a single answer to this question.  In the end it depends on the agency doing the vetting ability to verify the information you provided.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about legal requirements, not about security in itself.

Comment: @D3C4FF I was waiting to see if others had something to say, but seems that your answer is the definitively answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe It depends on the level of security clearance you require.
For example, SIS/MI6 work that requires DV clearances has the [following criteria](https://www.sis.gov.uk/careers/working-for-us/security-vetting/what-is-security-clearance.html)

> The minimum criteria for attaining a valid DV clearance are:
>
> - The candidate must have been a resident in the UK for the majority of the past ten years and
> - The candidate must have residency information that is verifiable.

This [guide here](http://www.arm.co.uk/job-seekers/security-clearance---our-guide.aspx) has the following values for residency for the following levels of clearance:

- DV(Developed Vetting) = 10 years minimum residency
- SC(Security Check) = 5 years minimum residency
- CTC(Counter Terrorist Check) = 3 years minimum residency

The following levels of security clearance don't specifically mention residency or citizenship as far as i can determine.

- EBS / Enhanced Baseline Standard
- BPSS / Basic Personnel Security Standard
- NATO Cleared
- MPS / Metropolitan Police Service
- SIA / Security Industry Authority
- CRB / Criminal Records Bureau
- ECRB / Enhanced Criminal Records Bureau

In case you aren't aware, the system in the UK is like Australia, you require the company you will work for to 'Sponsor' your application for clearance (basically you have to be better than everyone else in the UK that doesn't already have clearance).

In Australia, you are required to have citizenship to get the most 'simple' baseline clearance.

Comment: Thanks. That answers for me whether UK or Australia short 1-2 year contracts would even be a possibility for me. Every UK posting I've seen that interested me required SC clearance. I don't currently live there, no do I have citizenship. My wife is a physicist, so the possibility of moving around a lot is pretty high. Labs doing research in her area of specialty are few and scattered. I, on the other hand can get some kind of tech work pretty much anywhere.